# Unable to use nmap

Tags: nmap

Just trying to figure out the ip of a wifi device.
I'm using:

```
fpollano@debianfx:~$ nmap -n 191.168.0.0-254

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-19 21:06 EDT
Nmap done: 255 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 103.19 seconds
fpollano@debianfx:~$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=3.36 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=3.35 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=3.34 ms
```

nmap return no hosts, but a simple ping, show an host alive ( indeed, there is others ;) )

Comment: as @BruceEdiger answer below, indeed was a typo in the address: 191 instead of 192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nmap -n` is going to do a TCP port scan on the 255 IP addresses you specified. If the machines at those IP addresses have no ports open, I'm thinking you won't get anything back.

`ping` uses ICMP packets, which is at the IP level, "below" the TCP level. It only identifies machines (ethernet interfaces, really) not the ports open on the machines.  Try this:

```
nmap -n -sn 191.168.0.0-254
```

If that doesn't work, and it probably won't, notice that you're using "191" as the first byte of the `nmap` address range, but "192" in the `ping` command.

Comment: LOL, true a stupid mistake:)